# Show the integal $\int_a^b \sqrt{N} \Big( \frac{1 + \cos 2\pi(u-x) }{2} \Big)^N du $ is uniform bounded in $N$ and $x$

Tags: real-analysis, probability

The problem is just  a part of [Sourav Chatterjee' lecture notes on probability](https://souravchatterjee.su.domains/stats310notes.pdf) exercise 9.13.11 ,
with $ 0 < a < b < 1$ and $ x \in [0 , 1 ]$ .  My attempt is that

$\int_a^b \sqrt{N} \Big( \frac{1 + \cos 2\pi(u-x) }{2} \Big)^N du
=  \int_a^b \sqrt{N} \big( \cos \pi(u-x) \big)^{2N} du \leq \frac{\sqrt{N} }{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  \big( \cos s \big)^{2N} ds = \frac{\sqrt{N} }{2^{2N}\pi} \binom{2N}{N}  $

But  i don't know how to estimate this result , though the numerical computation suggests it is
roughly bounded by 0.57 . Or there's anthoer method to esitmate the integral ? From the context
of the problem , I guess I'll need to use Stone-Weierstrass theorem and trgonometric approximation
? But I'm not sure how to do it .

Comment: Stirlings approximation might be helpful. See feller volume 1 or wikipedia page for non-asymptomatic bounds.

Comment: Thanks! the bounds work very well !

Comment: The integral is bounded above by its limit as $N\to \infty$, the $0.57$ you found (which is actually $1/\sqrt{\pi}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rewrite the integral as

$$I = \int_{a-x}^{b-x}\sqrt{N}\left(\frac{1+\cos 2\pi u}{2}\right)^Ndx = \int_{(a-x)\sqrt{N}}^{(b-x)\sqrt{N}}\cos^{2N}\frac{\pi t}{\sqrt{N}}dt$$

Notice that for $0 < a < b < 1$

$$\sqrt{N} \notin [(a-x)\sqrt{N},(b-x)\sqrt{N}]$$

and

$$0 \in [(a-x)\sqrt{N},(b-x)\sqrt{N}]$$

only when $x \in [a,b] \subset [0,1]$. When $0$ is not contained the interval of either integral (since the transformation $u \mapsto \frac{t}{\sqrt{N}}$ preserves the location of $0$), the integral is bounded by sequence of the form $(b-a) \sqrt{N}r^N$ where

$$r = \max\left\{\cos^2[\pi(a-x)],\cos^2[\pi(b-x)]\right\} < 1$$

In the more interesting case, the integral forms a monotonically increasing sequence (an exercise for OP), which is bounded above by its limit, given by

$$\longrightarrow \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi^2 t^2}\:dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \approx 0.56418958_\cdots$$

or $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$ in the special case where $x=a,b$.